# How can I upgrade python to 3.8 in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, version, updates

I noticed that in my Anaconda Navigator, the system shows that Python 3.8.3 has been installed, but as I checked the version on Jupiter notebook, it's 3.7.6. I'm wondering is there a way I can update the latest Python on the notebook? Thanks:)

Comment: You need to update the Python installation which the notebook is using.

Comment: @AMC Thanks for the comment! How can I do that?

Comment: This is an extremely common topic, have you done any research? Are there any specific issues?

Answer (score 2):

In the Jupyter Notebook, select KERNEL >> CHANGE KERNEL and choose the Conda virtual environment with Python 3.8.

Comment: Should I run this on my terminal? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should run the command on your terminal

Comment: I just tried that but it still shows me 3.7.6

Comment: @ DapperDuck  It still does not, but I just noticed 3.8.3 is in a different environment called py, but my notebook is in base(root)

Comment: Isn’t the goal to update **Python** to a newer version?

Comment: @AMC the OP already has the new version of python installed. The problem is that their jupyter notebook is running in the wrong python version.

Comment: @zhengrong edited my answer. Check if it works

Comment: @DapperDuck _The problem is that their jupyter notebook is running in the wrong python version._ Right, but updating the jupyter package won’t change that.

Comment: @AMC understood, that's just what I found googling it. I have updated my answer based on the new information.